# RegEx Tokenizer: split text into words, digits, punctuation, and spacing (do not delete anything)

Tags: python, regex, nltk, tokenize

I *almost* found the answer to this question in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214177/regex-tokenizer-to-split-a-text-into-words-digits-and-punctuation-marks) (samplebias's answer); however I need to split a phrase into words, digits, punctuation marks, and spaces/tabs. I also need this to preserve the order in which each of these things occurs (which the code in that thread already does).

So, what I've found is something like this:

```
    from nltk.tokenize import *
    txt = "Today it's   07.May 2011. Or 2.999."
    regexp_tokenize(txt, pattern=r'\w+([.,]\w+)*|\S+')
    ['Today', 'it', "'s", '07.May', '2011', '.', 'Or', '2.999', '.']
```

But this is the kind of list I need to yield:

```
    ['Today', ' ', 'it', "'s", ' ', '\t', '07.May', ' ', '2011', '.', ' ', 'Or', ' ', '2.999', '.']
```

Regex has always been one of my weakpoints so after a couple hours of research I'm still stumped. Thank you!!

Comment: Why isn't `'07.May'` expanded into `'07', '.', 'May'`?

Comment: F.J, I'm not actually sure, it was a behavior borrowed over from the other thread. I'd like the behavior to be preserved, however, because I'd like an input like "pseudo-science" to remain as a single word-unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that something like this should work for you.  There is probably more in that regex than there needs to be, but your requirements are somewhat vague and don't exactly match up with the expected output you provided.

```
>>> txt = "Today it's \t07.May 2011. Or 2.999."
>>> p = re.compile(r"\d+|[-'a-z]+|[ ]+|\s+|[.,]+|\S+", re.I)
>>> slice_starts = [m.start() for m in p.finditer(txt)] + [None]
>>> [txt[s:e] for s, e in zip(slice_starts, slice_starts[1:])]
['Today', ' ', "it's", ' ', '\t', '07', '.', 'May', ' ', '2011', '.', ' ', 'Or', ' ', '2', '.', '999', '.']
```

Comment: Okay this seems pretty safe, thank you. But is there any way we could preserve the words "it's" or "isn't" ? I guess it just shouldn't split a word on internal apostrophes?

Comment: Modified the regex so that it will not split on apostrophes or hyphens, however it currently isn't checking to make sure they are internal.  If that is an issue I can try to modify it.

Comment: Awesome, this is great. Sorry I've been slow to respond, school is just starting up over here.

Answer (score 0):

In the regex `\w+([.,]\w+)*|\S+`, `\w+([.,]\w+)*` captures words and `\S+` captures other non-whitespace.

In order to capture spaces and tabs as well, try this: `\w+([.,]\w+)*|\S+|[ \t]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully compliant with the expected output you provided, some more details in the question would help, but anyway:

```
>>> txt = "Today it's   07.May 2011. Or 2.999."
>>> regexp_tokenize(txt, pattern=r"\w+([.',]\w+)*|[ \t]+")
['Today', ' ', "it's", ' \t', '07.May', ' ', '2011', ' ', 'Or', ' ', '2.999']
```