# python regex: how to split string into distinct groups based on alphabets, digits and punctuation

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regular expressions using python 2.7

Given a sentence(assume lowercase and ascii) such as:

```
input = 'i like: a, b, 007 and c!!'
```

How would I tokenize the input string into

```
['i', 'like', ':', 'a', ',', 'b', ',', '007', 'and', 'c', '!!']
```

I can write the automata and code the transition matrix in C++, but I would like to do this in python

I am unable to come up with a regex that will match these distinct classes of alphabets, digits and punctuations in one go.

I have seen a couple of stackoverflow posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214177/regex-tokenizer-to-split-a-text-into-words-digits-and-punctuation-marks) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987356/regex-tokenizer-split-text-into-words-digits-punctuation-and-spacing-do-not), but do not quite follow their approaches.

I have tried this for some time now and I would appreciate your help on this.

P.S: This is not a homework question

Comment: i have used the 're' module and can group 
[a-z]+ , [0-9]+ , [^a-z0-9\s]+ separately, but am unable to group them into one regex that produces the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> text = 'i like: a, b, 007 and c!!'
>>> re.findall('\w+|[{0}]+'.format(punctuation),text)
['i', 'like', ':', 'a', ',', 'b', ',', '007', 'and', 'c', '!!']
```

This also works but finds any non-whitespace character if it doesn't find alphanumeric characters

```
>>> re.findall('\w+|\S+',text)
['i', 'like', ':', 'a', ',', 'b', ',', '007', 'and', 'c', '!!']
```

Comment: What is `[{0}]` doing in your first example? I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: substitutes the `0th` argument to format which is punctuation. Takes any letter from punctuation.

Comment: your answer is elegant. A minor detail - i wished to group alphabets, digits and punctuation separately, whereas \w treats '_' also a word character. I guess replacing \w with [a-z0-9] in your solution should work. I am marking your answer as accepted. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I didn't know that from reading the question but you can easily add that in as you said by adding more categories.